# How to ALTER Camunda database to accept long string variables?

Tags: java, h2, business-process-management, camunda

I am facing an issue when passing a long string variable (more than 4000 characters in length) via Camunda Engine.

[image]

Is there anyway to alter the camunda database to avoid this exception, or disable the default long string restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.variable.Variables;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.variable.Variables.SerializationDataFormats;

variableMap.put("Authorization", Variables
                              .objectValue(authorization)
                                  // tells the engine to use java serialization for persisting the value 
                              .serializationDataFormat(SerializationDataFormats.JAVA)  
                              .create());
```

Comment: So, you serialize with that, but how do you retrieve the value with variables.get()?